# How to use Facebook access token for a service with Spring

Tags: android, facebook, spring, google-plus

I am building a android application that requires Sign in. For this, I have used the Facebook and Google+ sdk for android. I use Facebook and Google+ sign in instead create my own sign in.

This app will connect with a Spring service to access a storage data. This data is private for each user, therefore I need a log in system. The data will be stored in a database in the server.

My question is, how I can link the data with the user?

I have thought obtain the access token in the android app and pass it to the service. With this access token, can the server obtain, for example, the user id to link the data with the user? or are there other ways to  do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow either of below mentioned approaches:

- You can pass the access token from the app to the server and using the graph API, get the user details including user id, email ,etc. Once you get this information you can link it to your data.
- Using the access token in the app itself and calling the graph API from the app, get the user details and then pass the user id from the app to the spring service.

This is the simplest approach you can follow.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that the first option is more secure, no? If you only pass the id, someone can extract the id from Facebook user and make an api request with this id. This way, I am not secure if the user is the real user.

Comment: Yeah passing the access token is more logical.